# Using a cookie to determine if a user needs to log in again, Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I've a login page (using a HTML form) that when a user enters a password (pre-determined) they can view a site. What I would like is, when the user is logged in, a cookie timer will start and last for 24 hours, when 24 hours expires, they will have to log back in when they view the site. I've done a fair bit of research into this but am struggling a small bit to understand due to my lack of experience with Node.js. I appreciate that using a pre-determined password is poor practice but for what I'm doing, it suits.

Below is the code I have in the server.js file. I had a normal login working prior to starting with cookies so it's just the cookie part I'm having trouble with. Obviously the code below is missing something like MaxAge but I dunno where to implement it. 
Thanks

```js
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.user_id) {
    res.send('You are not authorized to view this page');
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
app.get('/home', checkAuth, function (req, res) {
  res.send('if you are viewing this page it means you are logged in');
});

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  var post = req.body;
  if (req.body.name == "login"){
    req.session.user_id = "login";
    res.redirect('/home');
  } else {
    res.send('Bad user/pass');
  }
});
```

Comment: Have a look at docs of express-session options. You can set *maxAge or *expires* options.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialise your session, add the maxAge to the cookie.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'your secret key',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 1440000
    }
}));
```

This sets the maxAge of all the cookie. Post which you can check if the request is authenticated.